# How to delete a row from an sqlite table with a constraint failed error

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

How to delete a row from an sqlite table:

I'm trying and get the "constraint failed" error

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM cataloge WHERE id = 30;
constraint failed
```

here's the structure of the table:

[image: table structure]

Comment: does catalogue have children effected by a referential integrity constraint?

Comment: how would I find that out? I added a screenshot of the table structure above. thanks

Comment: Look for the tables in which you have cataloge.id as foreign key. Those tables also could not have rows with 30 as id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sundar's answer solved this for me:

Look for the tables in which you have cataloge.id as foreign key. Those tables also could not have rows with 30 as id. – sundar